# ruby gem mechanize for in `fetch': 405 => Net::HTTPMethodNotAllowed

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using the ruby's Mechanize gem to login the website.Here comes my problem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://mail.163.com/')
form = page.form('login163')
form.username = 'myaccount'
form.password = 'mypassword'
page = agent.submit(form)
```

when I run the script, it just cant't work, the error is: "in `fetch': 405 => Net::HTTPMethodNotAllowed for http://mail.163.com/". What should I do?

Comment: That url won't load for me but my guess is change the action or the method.

Comment: It is quite confused me that why I use the same code model to login the gmail then it works quite well, but it failed in some other websites?

Comment: Possibly the form is modified by javascript. Mechanize won't know about things like that so you have to do it yourself.